# AngularJS: $rootscope and $scope bind issue

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller.

```
angular.module('xyz').controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.myVar = 123;
    $rootScope.myVar = $scope.myVar;
});
```

Now the issue is that for some reason I have to save the same value in $rootScope also. But after I save this value, if the user updates the value in the view, the value gets updated in $scope. But due to binding $rootScope takes precedence and therefor angular updates the value of `$scope.myVar` with what is in `$rootScope.myVar`.

Is there a way where a reference is not created between these two variables.

Comment: `$scope.myVar = angular.copy($rootScope.myVar)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a primitive type like a number/string/boolean/etc... it won't be a reference (your example is this type). If it's an object/function/array/etc.. it will be. So to destroy the reference you'd use angular.copy:

```
$rootScope.myVar = angular.copy($scope.myVar);
```

Reference:

```
angular.module('xyz').controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.myVar = 123;
    $rootScope.myVar = $scope.myVar; //won't be a reference
});

angular.module('xyz').controller('MyController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.myVar = { data: 123 };
    $rootScope.myVar = $scope.myVar; //will be a reference
    $rootScope.myVar = { data: $scope.myVar.data }; //won't be a reference
});
```

Comment: It is a simple string in the variable. That is what baffles me. I know that it should not create a reference for string variable.

Comment: paste your actual code, i have a feeling you're still using a reference.

Comment: Will do it in a bit. Don't have access to my machine at the moment.

Comment: I fixed it. It was some other issue. But reference issues are fixed by `angular.copy`. P.S. Before `angular.copy` I used to do `var xyz = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(abc))`